# Example of a measure on a metric space that behaves differently than Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let  $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $B(x,R)$ is the ball around $x$ of radius $R$.

The motivation for this question is the observation that for a sequence $a_n$ tending to zero, then $\mu( B(x,R) ) - \mu(B(x,R-a_n)) = O(a_n),$ regardless of the dimension $d$. I.e., the rate at which the measure of $\mu(B(x,R-a_n))$ approaches $\mu(B(x,R))$ is linear in $a_n$. The rate is at least this fast if the measure $\mu$ were a probability measure over $\mathbb{R}^d$ that is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure with bounded density.

I assume this does not always have to be the case!

Could one of you come up with an example of a probability measure on a metric space $\mu$ so that $\mu( B(x,R) ) - \mu(B(x,R-a_n)) = O(b_n)$, where $b_n$ is any sequence tending to zero?

I'd be interested in the example even if it only holds for one "special" ball, not necessarily all balls.

Comment: Hmm, is it really linear? Unless I'm missing something, we have a difference of squares in $d=2$, of cubes in $d=3$, of quartics in $d=4$... all with different decay rates

Comment: @FShrike My thought is that $R^d - (R-a_n)^d= \sum_{i=1}^d c_i a_n^i R^{d-i} = O(a_n)$, i.e. the term decreasing to zero the slowest is the $a_n^1$ term.

Comment: In $d=1$, letting $\mu$ be the [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution) gives an example for $x=0$ and $R=1$. You will have $\mu(B(0,1-a)) = \mu(B(0,1)) - O(a^{\log_3 2})$. You can get other rates by choosing different Cantor sets, removing the middle $\alpha$ instead of the middle third each time. More generally, if you use a measure defined by removing the middle $\alpha_n$ at the $n^{th}$ stage, you should be able to get an arbtrary rate $b_n$.

Comment: Thanks @MikeEarnest! That is a very nice suggestion. I'll think about it.